# Замена ссылок в хтмл коде

Tags: php, ссылки

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с таким: имеется сайт, файлов, и особенно ссылок и форм в нём достаточно много. Мне нужно в конце каждой ссылки или в конце каждой ссылки формы что бы php дописывал GET параметры. если сделать `file_get_contents` то он загонит в переменную php код вместе с хтмл, а мне нужно загнуть в переменную именно хтмл код, что бы при этом php был в коде обработан, и остался только хтмл, что то типа парсера. дальше регуляркой все ссылки заменить и вывести код. как можно такое реализовать? Или может есть альтернативные способы?

P.S. парсер и остальные файлы должны быть на одном хосте, а не на разных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне пришла такая мысль, почему бы фронтэндом это не сделать? Скажем дописать в конец каждой страницы что то подобное:

```
<script>
    var f1 = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++) { f1[i].href += '?anyget=123'; }
    var f2 = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++) { f1[i].action += '?anyget=123'; }
</script>
```

Если по PHP то мне кажется смотреть в сторону буфера вывода: http://www.php.su/functions/?ob_start

Что то подобное:

```
<?php

function callback($buffer) {

// заменить все apples на oranges
return (ereg_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));

}

ob_start("callback");

?>

<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.
</body>
</html>

<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score -1):

помогут preg_replace и регулярные выражения.

Comment: как выводится уже сформированный хтмл-код на данном сайте?